# How do I add a list item with a class name identical to the unordered list id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, append

I am generating a list of items with different state names as class names. These list items need to be appended to the unordered list with the same class name but as an id. So currently the DOM looks like:

```
<ul id="Montana"></ul>
<ul id="Nebraska"></ul>
<ul id="Oregon"></ul>
<li class="Montana>Hello World</li>
<li class="Montana>Hello World</li>
<li class="Oregon>Hello World</li>
<li class="Nebraska>Hello World</li>
<li class="Montana>Hello World</li>
<li class="Montana>Hello World</li>
<li class="Oregon>Hello World</li>
<li class="Montana>Hello World</li>
```

Normally I'd just append via a for loop like:

```
for(var i =0; i < something.length; i++){ $('#' + something[i]).append('.' + something[i]);
```

But that is currently not working. Honestly I might just be having a mini-stroke and need a slap in the face.

Any advice? Slap in the face?

EDIT:

I am returned a JSON blob. One of its key/value pairs is "state": whatever the state is. I run a for loop thru that blob and create a bunch of ul's and li's with those class/id names. I'd show all of my code but I also add a bunch of SVG related stuff that would just bloat the question.

Comment: Could use more code context...

Comment: And what is `something` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? Get all the `li`s, iterate through them, find the ID that matches each `li`s class and append the `li`.

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0, numLis = lis.length; i < numLis; ++i)
{
    document.getElementById(lis[i].className).appendChild(lis[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$('li').each(function(index, li){
   li = $(li);
   li.appendTo($('ul#' + li.attr('class')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why you're adding state names as classes/ids, I don't recommend adding this kind of thing (generally page data) to html in attributes (unless if you add it to the 'data' attribute). Generally classes and ids are for styling and functionality, data should be in a separate element (and hidden if it should be).

You can make an element hierarchy instead. Something like this:

```
<li class="state-li">
  <div class="text">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <div class="state-name hidden">
    Montana
  </div>
</li>
```

then you can use jQuery to easily find children of class `state-li`

but to answer your question (jQuery):

```
elementToAppendTo = $('#elementId');
stateList = [list of states];
var length = stateList.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  $(elementToAppendTo).append("<li id='" + stateList[i] + "'></li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! I ended up finessing a:

```
$('.' + something[i].stateName).appendTo('#' + something[i].stateName);
```

Into doing the trick. With that said I'm pretty sure the advice you all offered would also work.